# Too many results in SQL SELECT

Tags: sql

Here is my SQL Statement...

```
SELECT     
    dbo.PPMASTER.Per_or_Bus, 
    dbo.PPMASTER.Assessment_Date, 
    dbo.PPBUSMST.Assessment_Number, 
    dbo.PPBUSMST.Year
FROM dbo.PPBUSMST INNER JOIN dbo.PPMASTER 
                  ON dbo.PPBUSMST.Assessment_Number = dbo.PPMASTER.Assessment_Number
WHERE (dbo.PPBUSMST.Assessment_Number = @Assessment)
```

The problem is that I get duplicate results stemming from the `Assessment_Date`. Each `Assessment_Date` should only have one result per Year. Any ideas?

Here is some of the results sample data...

```
**B 1996-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 1996**
B   1996-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 1997
B   1996-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 1998
B   1996-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 1999
B   1996-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 2000
B   1996-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 2001
B   1996-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 2002
B   1997-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 1996
**B 1997-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 1997**
B   1997-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 1998
B   1997-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 1999
B   1997-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 2000
B   1997-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 2001
B   1997-05-29 00:00:00 9005450 2002
B   1998-04-27 00:00:00 9005450 1996
B   1998-04-27 00:00:00 9005450 1997
**B 1998-04-27 00:00:00 9005450 1998**
B   1998-04-27 00:00:00 9005450 1999
B   1998-04-27 00:00:00 9005450 2000
B   1998-04-27 00:00:00 9005450 2001
B   1998-04-27 00:00:00 9005450 2002
```

The ones I have **'d are the results I actually want to achieve

Comment: And did you try running a select count(assessment_date) on each table to make sure they are distinct?

Comment: Can you show the duplicate rows?

Comment: Please post some sample data that demonstrates the problem. Creating a sqlfiddle would also be helpful.

Comment: The usual cause of this kind of problem is multiple matching rows in the table you're joining with. It can be fixed either by making the join use more columns so only one row matches, or by joining with a subquery that uses `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: @Barmar OR the data could be fixed.

Comment: (offtopic) I personally think questions with SQL should only be asked along with a sqlfiddle of the tables

Comment: @MikeCheel If the data is incorrect..

Comment: I have found that "fixing" the query using distinct usually means that I'm using the wrong query.

Comment: I have found that comments with > 10 upvotes are typically right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at what you've marked as wanting to achieve, it implies that your `join` conditions are incomplete. The rows you want are not only the ones where `PPBUSMST.Assessment_Number = PPMASTER.Assessment_Number`, but also where `YEAR(PPMASTER.Assessment_Date) = PPBUSMST.[Year]`.

Adding that to your `join` conditions should resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Matthew! I had tried doing a similar thing to the WHERE clause, but that didn't work properly, although I'm not sure why. However, your suggestion was spot on. Thanks!